# How do you get all project macros and their values from .vcxproj file

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to parse a group of vcxproj files and am running into difficulties with their use of [macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in properties.

A trivial example is

```
<ProgramDatabaseFile>$(OutDir)$(ProjectName).pdb</ProgramDatabaseFile>
```

$(Outdir) and $(ProjectName) are generally relatively easy to infer from the file, although this particular one has quite a few different configurations.

I was wondering, rather than reinventing the wheel (again), is there a utility or library (preferably C#) which will derive from a project file all of its macros and their associated values?

Obviously msBuild and Visual Studio are able to extract this information, so it seems like they might share some library or program to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project
```

class has what I need in it's Properties field